# Maven sibling module dependency without specifying the version

Tags: java, maven, parent-child, pom.xml, dependency-management

I have a multi-module maven application with below dependencies; we are using maven release plugin for one of the modules and its version is auto-incremented by every release build.

```
Parent module
   |---Module A
   |---Module B - version is auto incremented by maven release plugin
   |---Module C - has a dependency on module B
```

Question: How to add dependency of Module B in Module C, without specifying the version. Currently, I am hard-coding the version but after every release I have to manually update the version to latest.
Just to be clear, I want to have a dependency as below.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.my.application</groupId>
        <artifactId>Module B</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I tried using, project.version, but it gives the parent version and of no help. I tried using dependencymanagement but could not get it working. Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: Simply use `<version>${project.version}</version>`?

Comment: thanks for the reply....${project.version} is not same as Module B version...it always returns parent's version for  ${project.version} which is 1.0.0 in my case

Comment: @Ansh why would you use different versions between your parent and sub modules? In most cases you would use the same version and `mvn versions:set` and release plugin take care of keeping them in sync.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your version as an open ended version range as below. This will pick the latest available.

`<version>[1.2.3,)</version>`

But, make sure your Module `B`'s versioning follows the standard.

Comment: thanks Nipun...seems like it worked for me...will have to wait for a couple for release cycles to validate...Module B uses the maven release plug-in so assuming the version will be incremented by standard